# Mock angular service not being detected in jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, service, jasmine

I'm new to testing with Jasmine and I've hit an issue while writing an test for a service I've written in my AngularJS application.

This is my test code:

```
describe('AccountCtrl', function () {


    beforeEach(module('zamolxian.my_account'));


    var mockCountryService = {

        //console:log("hello")
        //countryList: {"name": "Zimbabwe", "cca2": "ZW", "callingCode": ["263"]}

         checkPhone: function (countryName, phoneNumber) {
         if (phoneNumber.length == 10 && countryName.length > 2) {
         return true;
         }
         return false;
         }
    };



it('should be able to call the check phone from the the country service', function () {
        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, mockCountryService) {
            var scope = $rootScope.$new;


            var ctrl = $controller('AccountCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                countryListing: mockCountryService
            });
            console.log(countryListing.checkPhone("RO","235556789"));
            expect('1').toBeDefined();

        });
    });
});
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Linux) AccountCtrl should be able to call the check phone from the the country service FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.20+sha.d4ac254/$injector/unpr?p0=mockCountryServiceProvider%20%3C-%20mockCountryService
            at Error (native)
            at /var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:471
            at /var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:32:125
            at Object.c [as get] (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
            at /var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:32:193
            at c (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:30:200)
            at Object.d [as invoke] (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:30:417)
            at workFn (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2143:20)
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2129:37)
            at null.<anonymous> (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/src/app/my_account/my_account.spec.js:49:9)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2128:25)
            at null.<anonymous> (/var/www/Zamolxian/apps/source/src/app/my_account/my_account.spec.js:49:9)
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Linux): Executed 5 of 5 (1 FAILED) (0.411 secs / 0.037 secs)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed ?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to inject your service - `inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {...`

Comment: @doodeec so if  I understand you correctly I can use the service in the test without injecting it ?

Comment: since it is defined locally in `describe`, you already have it included in function closure, so why not...

Comment: @doodeec That works but I'm not sure now if I thought out this test through :)) in that it actually tests my service and controller.

Comment: @doodeec could you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as the chosen answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining `mockCountryService` inside `describe` function, you can ommit it's injection to `it` test case, it will be encapsulated in function's closure

```
it('should be able to call the check phone from the the country service', function () {
    inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {...
```